# React Native Fetch Blob issue pod not installing for IOS

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

Using React Native Fetch Blob to perform some action. But the IOS platform not installing in pod file. Showing this...

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-fetch-blob (from `../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob`) was resolved to 0.10.6, which depends on
      React/Core

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/Core`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

Kindly suggest some solution for that issue.

here is my pod file
This is my pod file i am not able to add React native fetch blob in it.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target  do
  # Pods for 
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/RNGestureHandler.podspec'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'



  target 'WorkreapMobileTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'WorkreapMobile-tvOS' do
  # Pods for WorkreapMobile-tvOS

  target 'WorkreapMobile-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

This is my pod file i am not able to add React native fetch blob in it.

Comment: Do you have `pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'` in your `Podfile`?

Comment: @KevinEtore yes i have this in my pod file

Comment: Did you try `pod install --repo-update` as it suggests

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In Root Directory

```
grep -rl "s.dependency 'React/Core'" node_modules/ | xargs sed -i '' 's=React/Core=React-Core=g'
```

Comment: If you are using gnu version of sed then use

```grep -rl "s.dependency 'React/Core'" node_modules/ | xargs sed -i 's=React/Core=React-Core=g'
```

Comment: Update: you may need to execute this command every time you add a new package and run `pod install`. In my case, after installing a new package I got the error again and executed this command and it's fixed again.

Answer (score 0):

without instruction it will took too many hours to find.
click=> nodemodules-> react-native-fetch-blob-> react-native-fetch-blob.podspec and then change "s.dependency 'React-Core'".

the pod will be download now but when you delete the node modules you have to install again don't forgot.